# Powering 3rd party sensors from DALI bus line

Tags: dali

I have some custom 5v arduino sensors that I'd like to power from a DALI bus line. Multimeter reports 27vdc on the bus line.

My naive assumption is that connecting a 27 to 5vdc voltage regulator would do the job as far as powering the arduinos are concerned. And it did work, however it appears to interfere with how other DALI devices are operating on that line.

Could someone please explain what I'm missing and if there's a correct method for drawing power off a DALI bus line.

Comment: Microchip have some examples in their appnotes. My guess is you have paralleled a capacitor across the bus which kills the data transmissions. You probably need a diode in series to isolate the power aection.

Comment: Which regulator is it, what does the schematic look like, and how much current the sensor takes from DALI wire?

Comment: 27V is a bit too high, should be 22.5V max and you need to watch how much current you draw depending on your PSU but it can be done. See the answer in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/560511/using-dali-2-bus-interfaceslave-to-supply-silabs-efr32xx

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.